# Java HttpSession

Tags: java, httpsession

Is HttpSession in java servlet is created only after

```
HttpSession s = request.getSession();
```

?

In my code I didn't write that, but when I use `if (request.getSession(false) == null) ...`, it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work? Do you have an exception? If your test returns something different from null it means the session already existed and it is not needed to create a new one.

Comment: So you get request.getSession(false)!=null. With some more code we may help you ...

Comment: I mean (request.getSession(false) == null) should be true, but it is false, I have no idea why

Comment: If it's not null it means the session already exists.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A HttpSession is created when calling request.getSession().

*But* if you access a JSP by default it will automatically create a session.This behaviour can be disabled by using: `<%@ page session="false">`

Are you using JSP?

Comment: That seems to also remove the session from the page request if one existed.

Comment: leif8: no, it does not remove session from the page for me

Comment: "A HttpSession is created when calling request.getSession()." Correct, unless a session already exists, then the current session is returned. See [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession()).

Answer (score 15):

Read JavaDocs, it says clearly:

This says, [request.getSession()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29)

> Returns the current session associated with this request, or if the request does not have a session, creates one.

And the other variant [request.getSession(isCreate)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29)

> Returns the current HttpSession associated with this request or, if there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session.
>
> **If create is false and the request has no valid HttpSession, this method returns null.**
>
> To make sure the session is properly maintained, you must call this method before the response is committed. If the container is using cookies to maintain session integrity and is asked to create a new session when the response is committed, an IllegalStateException is thrown.

---

*Update*

On a bit research, I have found that Session is *not* created unless `request.getSession()` is called *somewhere*. Since, `The servlet container uses this interface to create a session between an HTTP client and an HTTP server.` There are good chances that your Servlet container creates the Session for you by default.

*refer:*

1. Java Doc [HttpSession](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)
2. Discussion on JavaRaunch: [is HttpSession created automatically?](http://www.coderanch.com/t/361933/Servlets/java/HttpSession-created-automatically)

But, to be safer side, use `request.getSession()` to get session, and use `request.getSession(false)` only when you need to verify if a session has already been created.

Comment: That's what the question about. I DO NOT create any HttpSession. I don't use request.getSession(). The first time I check for it is if(request.getSession(FALSE) == null) it should be true, but it's not

Comment: `request.getSession()` is not the only way to create HTTP session.

Comment: @josh weird, I remember that some servlet-container maintain session from the first request. Could not find any supporting document, though.

Comment: @Nishant : Are the httpsessions shared between the whole domain are just the webapplication that created it?

Comment: @Ashwin Just the web applicaton. There are mechanism to shared session among difference instances of your app servers.

Comment: @Nishant : Please correct me if I am wrong. I want to see If I have understood it. When you first go to any web application in a domain the container creates a JSESSIONID cookie with a UUID value in it. Now each web application, can store some attributes for this UUID. These attributes are stored in a database and each web application has its own database. So if you set a request attribute for a jession ID in one web application, that attribute will not be present in another web application of the same domian. Am I right about the database thing and JSESSIONID?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Nishant's answer note that session can be created implicitly by JSP pages unless you configured them not to create a session with `<%@ page session = "false" %>`.

Answer (score 1):

To make it complete:

- session is not created, unless you call `request.getSession()`, in your servlet, use `request.getSession(false)` to get existing session without creating new session
- if you use JSP page, session is automatically created for you - variable `session` - unless you specify `<%@ page session="false" %>`
- even if your session is created automatically, you can use `session.isNew()` to find out, if it has been newly created

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove session cookies from browser and make another test. If it does not work then some other component is creating a new session before that call.